# Using ruby map method and excluding current user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an activity feed that currently show all activity including current user. My goal is to only update the feed with friends' activity and not the current user's activity. I believe it has something to do with the map(&:id) method, but I'm not positive. Any guidance would be super awesome!

activity.rb:

```
class Activity < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :targetable, polymorphic: true

  self.per_page = 10

  def self.for_user(user, options={})
    options[:page] ||= 1
    # return WillPaginate::Collection.new(1, per_page, 1) unless user
    friend_ids = user.friends.map(&:id).push(user.id)
    collection = where("user_id in (?)", friend_ids).order("created_at desc")

    if options[:since] && !options[:since].blank?
      since = DateTime.strptime( options[:since], '%s' )
      collection = collection.where("created_at > ?", since) if since
    end
    collection.page(options[:page])
  end

  def user_name
    user.name
  end

  def username
    user.username
  end

  def as_json(options={})
    super(
        only: [:action, :id, :targetable_id, :targetable_type, :created_at, :id],
        include: :targetable, 
        methods: [:user_name, :username]
    ).merge(options)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `.push(user.id)` is adding the user's own ID onto this list of friend IDs so if you just remove that you'll get the activities for just the friends.

`friends.map(&:id)` takes the list of the user's friends and maps this to a list of the IDs for those friends ready for use in the `where` condition on the next line i.e. it calls `id` on each friend and returns an array of the results of that.